# Increase counter value upon clicking button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, counter

I want to increase the counter value upon clicking a button. It does not work.

My HTML as follows:

```
<td>Infocomm Technology</td>
 <td>
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" value="Vote" ref="1" />
    </label>
 </td>
<td width="303">
  <span id="result1">1 votes</span>
</td>
```

My script as follows:

```
var vote = 1

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button1").click(function() {
         var vote = $("#result1").val();
         vote++ ;
         $('#submit').val();
     });
 });
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? And what did you intend to achieve with `$('#submit').val()`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to following:

```
var vote = 1

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button1").click(function() {
         vote++;
         $("#result1").html(vote);
     });
 });
```

You don't have to declare another variable called "vote" in in your click function. Simply execute vote++ for adding 1 and then add the current value to your result result span.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you're trying to change the value of `<span id="#result1">` when the user clicks the button, right? In that case, do this:

```
var vote = 1

$(document).ready(
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        vote++;
        $('#result1').text(vote + " votes");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi everyone. Thank you so so much.
yes i shouldnt have declared another variable called vote in the function.
thanks for helping me to solve this together. (: